# How to Create a Single Blog Page Using Thrive Themes (Architect)

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom theme for my blog using thrive themes. I have created a blog page that listed all my post but I'm stuck in creating the single post with a thrive theme.

How do I go about creating a single post that displays all contents? And how can I make it has also a comment form field and displaying my post comments?

PS: If you have any resources that can help me create this faster it will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reading developer WordPress docs? I'm sure this will help you if you go through it -> https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/

Comment: I haven't, Alright I will check out Thanks.